window print only modal contents
I have a LWC data table on Home Page with pagination that I am opening in modal without any pagination to show whole content with a scroll. Now I want to have a pritn functionality that will print only the content of the modal along the whole scrollable content into a PDF like windows.print(). But in my case it is printing the background of modal and rst of the browser tab page.
HTML:
<template if:true={isRenewalsModalOpen}>
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal_large">
            <div class="slds-modal__container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick={handlePrintRenewalsModalClose}>
                        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" alternative-text="close" size="small"></lightning-icon>
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                    </button>
                    <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium">Renewals</h2>
                </header>
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" style="height: calc(100% - 100px); overflow: auto;">
                    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Print" onclick={handlePrintRenewals}></lightning-button>
                    <lightning-datatable
                        key-field="id"
                        data={dataRenewals}
                        columns={columns}
                        onsort={handleSortRenewals}
                        sorted-by={sortedByRenewals}
                        sorted-direction={sortedDirectionRenewals}
                        hide-checkbox-column
                        data-id="renewalsTable">
                    </lightning-datatable>
                </div>
                <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <lightning-button variant="neutral" label="Close" onclick={handlePrintRenewalsModalClose}></lightning-button>
                    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Print" onclick={handlePrintRenewals}></lightning-button>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
    </template>

JS:
handlePrintRenewals() {
        //window.print();
        console.log('Print Renewals Data:'); // Debugging log
        const dataTable = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable[data-id="renewalsTable"]');
        console.log('Data Table:', dataTable); // Debugging log
    
        // if (dataTable) {
            console.log('inside if'); // Debugging log
            const printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=600,width=800');
            printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print Data</title>');
            // printWindow.document.write('<style>table { width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; } th, td { border: 1px solid black; padding: 8px; text-align: left; }</style>');
            // printWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
            // printWindow.document.write('<table><thead><tr>');
    
            // // Add table headers
            // this.columns.forEach(column => {
            //     printWindow.document.write(`<th>${column.label}</th>`);
            //     console.log('Column:', column.label); // Debugging log
            // });
    
            // printWindow.document.write('</tr></thead><tbody>');
    
            // // Add table rows
            // this.dataRenewals.forEach(row => {
            //     printWindow.document.write('<tr>');
            //     this.columns.forEach(column => {
            //         let cellValue = row[column.fieldName];
            //         if (column.type === 'url' && column.typeAttributes && column.typeAttributes.label) {
            //             cellValue = row[column.typeAttributes.label.fieldName];
            //         }
            //         printWindow.document.write(`<td>${cellValue}</td>`);
            //         console.log('Cell Value:', cellValue); // Debugging log
            //     });
            //     printWindow.document.write('</tr>');
            // });
    
            // printWindow.document.write('</tbody></table>');
            printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            printWindow.document.close();
            printWindow.print();
        // } else {
        //     console.error('Data table not found'); // Debugging log
        //     this.showToast('Error', 'Data table not found', 'error');
        // }
    }


A quick web search returns several results, including this possible solution.  You should review the other results as well.
